# How do you create a dynamic number of divs with dynamic content in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I know you would use ngFor, but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Basically I want want to create the div below n times, replacing the 0 with 1 for the 2nd div, 2 for the 3rd div, and so on...

```
<div class="box">
    <p class="dut-text dut-title">
        {{list[0].data}}
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Creates below div for each value in `items`:

```
<div class="box" *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">
    <p class="dut-text dut-title">
        {{list[i].data}}
    </p>
</div>
```

```
class MyComponent {
  items = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}
```

**Update**

alternative interpretation of your question (see comments)

```
<div class="box" *ngFor="let item of list">
    <p class="dut-text dut-title">
        {{item.data}}
    </p>
</div>
```

```
class MyComponent {
  list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}
```

Comment: You should be able to do `{{item.data}}` instead of `{{list[i].data}}` and thus you don't need `let i=index` in the `*ngFor` statement.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure. The question says "replacing 0 with 1 for the 2nd ...". I guess it depends on what @Jon actually wants to accomplish.

Comment: Isn't that just because the index is zero-based? The 2nd div (visually) would have index 1.

Comment: Your assumptions are true if `items` and `list` are identical but they could be different collections. The question is just not clear enough.

Comment: Yeah, that's true.